# AdMob ad banner not changing position (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, swift3, position, admob

Hi there I'm trying to change the position of my AdMob banner in one of my scenes. The ad displays successfully (and is hidden successfully) whenever I set it to be, but it doesn't take the position I give it. It's always on the top. How can I set it to position at the bottom of the screen?

```
    banner.frame = CGRect(x:0.0,
                          y:-(self.view?.frame.size.height)! + banner.frame.size.height,
                          width:banner.frame.size.width,
                          height:banner.frame.size.height)

    banner = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
    banner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-xxxx"

    banner.rootViewController = gameViewController

    let request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = ["xxxx"]
    banner.load(request)

    self.view?.addSubview(banner)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initialising a new banner after setting the frame, switch lines 1 and 2 around.

Comment: Wow I feel dumb lol. Thanks so much for the super fast repsonse!

Comment: No problem, hope it helped.